# Select Sitecore archived items directly

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

`Sitecore.Context.Database.Archives["archive"].GetEntries(pageIndex, pageSize)` 
statement is returning `ArchiveEntry` list that is not what I want, instead I need the actual Items to be retrieved.

How can I get the Sitecore Items from the archive list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Those items are archived. That means that you cannot access them directly and you cannot access their custom fields. You need to restore them first using:

```
Sitecore.Context.Database.Archives["archive"].RestoreItem(archivalId)
```

This is similar like using recycle bin in Windows - you move files there and you can not edit them unless you restore them back.

Comment: I cannot perform any restorations, but I need to display the archived item's details(some custom field values), so that the user is explained why it is archived.

Comment: As I wrote and explained above, you don't have access to custom fields of the archived items. You have base info (ItemId, Name, Original Location, ParentId) in the **Archive Entry** class. There is no way for accessing other fields without restoring the item.